# Bootstrap 4 - DataTable search not working on rows added by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the Bootstrap 4 search tool. If the rows are added manually in `tbody` the search works, but if I add a new row from jQuery then search doesn't see those rows.

This is the body of the table.
Below is the function that adds a new row to the table:

```js
function addProduct(name, id, price, quantity = 1) 
{
    var template = $("#product-template").clone(true, true);
    var existingRow = $("#product-table").find('#product' + id);
    template.removeClass("disabled");
    if (existingRow.length > 0) 
    {
        var quantity = parseInt(existingRow.find('.prod-quantity').text()) + 1;
        existingRow.find('.prod-quantity').text(quantity);
        calculateTotalPrice(id);
        return;
    }
    template.attr("unit-price", price);
    template.attr("id", "product" + id);
    template.find('.prod-name').attr("title", name);
    template.attr("productID", id);
    template.find('.prod-name').text(name);
    template.find('.prod-quantity').text(quantity);
    template.find('.total-price').text(price);
    $(template).css("display", "table-row");
    $("#product-table").append(template);
    calculateTotalPrice(id);
    orderTableData();
    calculateTotalPayment();
}
```

```html
<tbody id="product-table" class="prd">
    <tr id="product-template" class="tr-prod disabled">
        <td class="text-center nr-order" id=""></td>
        <td class="prod-name" contenteditable="true" title="" style="background-color: white; color:black;">a</td>
        <td class="prod-quantity text-center" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: white; color:black">1</td>
        <td class="total-price text-center"></td>
        <td class="col-sm-3  text-center " style="width: 25px!important;">
            <i class="fas fa-minus-circle remove" title="Elimină" style="font-size:20px;color:#F08080;width:20px">
            </i>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="product-template-1" class="tr-prod disabled">
        <td class="text-center nr-order" id=""></td>
        <td class="prod-name" contenteditable="true" title="" style="background-color: white; color:black;">b</td>
        <td class="prod-quantity text-center" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: white; color:black">1</td>
        <td class="total-price text-center"></td>
        <td class="col-sm-3  text-center " style="width: 25px!important;">
            <i class="fas fa-minus-circle remove" title="Elimină" style="font-size:20px;color:#F08080;width:20px">
            </i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I don't know why, but the rows added with the `addProduct()` function don't appear in the search, and not only that, but they disappear completely when I'm searching for something.

What am I missing, maybe I should update the table after I add a new row?

Comment: Is this simple table which is being populated by server side code where is your search function? Please create jsfiddle with your working demo. There we can see whats an issue.

Comment: yes, but it's a pretty long procedure because I have to delete the php code and select the parts of the code that I need to put in JSFiddle. The search function is from Bootstrap, so I have no function. To better understand what kind of table I use I attach a link to Bootstrap 4 Datatables
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/search/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#product-table').DataTable();
        $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');

        function addProduct(name, id, price, quantity = 1)

            //instead $("#product-table").append(template)
            table.row.add([
                'td 1',
                'td 2',
                'td 3',
                ...
                'td n',
            ])
            table.draw();
            
        }
    });
    </script>
```